# Как рандомно менять цвет у блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть например несколько блоков. Как можно скриптом указать 4 цвета, по умолчанию, которые будут менять фон program рандомно при заходе на страницу. Но чтобы при этом не повторялись. А если блоков больше 4, то выводить цвет из заданных заново.

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не ясно на какой вопрос тут отвечать. Какая **конкретно** проблема

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский тут один вопрос. Как менять рандомно цвет у блока. И несколько условий, как именно он должен меняться

Comment: @hellokitViki так а почему вы это не сделали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот метод с использованием `Array.splice()`

```js
const programBLocks = document.querySelectorAll('.program');
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];

function randomGenerateColor() {
  let tempColors = [...colors];
  programBLocks.forEach(element => {
    let countColors = tempColors.length;

    if (countColors === 0) {
      tempColors = [...colors];
    }

    let colorIndex = generateRandomNumber(0, tempColors.length);
    let color = tempColors[colorIndex];
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    tempColors.splice(colorIndex, 1);
  })
}

function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

randomGenerateColor();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.program {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="program"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: выглядит не очень когда цвет четвёртого блока и пятого совпадает

Comment: переменная countColors  не понятно для чего создаётся и не используется что логично

Comment: element.style.backgroundColor = tempColors.splice(generateRandomNumber(0, tempColors.length), 1)[0];

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы присвоить всем блокам цвет без повторений надо:

1. Объявить массив с цветами.
2. Перемешать массив любым алгоритмом (их минимум десяток)
3. Далее **уже в из перемешанного** массива по порядку в цикле брать цвета и так же по порядку присваивать их блокам.
4. PROFIT